# PHP Sqlite3 множественная выборка

Tags: php, sqlite3

Появилась странная проблема при запросе:

`$result = $this->conn->query("SELECT student_id as id, avg(mark) as average FROM marks GROUP BY student_id ORDER BY avg(mark) DESC LIMIT 15;")->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);`

В `$result` я получаю `Array ( [id] => 1 [average] => 3.1739130434783 )`, хотя при запросе напрямую
*(через утилиту sqlite3.exe)*
я получаю полный список:

```
SQLite version 3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT student_id as id, avg(mark) as average FROM marks GROUP BY student_id ORDER BY avg(mark) DESC LIMIT 15;
1|3.17391304347826
2|3.0
7|1.0
6|1.0
5|1.0
4|1.0
3|1.0
sqlite>
```

Не знаю в чем проблема.

## Updates

Нашел, кажется, решение, но оно мне абсолютно не нравится.

```
while($row=$result->fetchArray()){
   // Do Something with $row
   print_r($row);
}
```

Есть ли способ в одну строку?

Comment: никакой проблемы нет. вы хотели получить массив результатов - вы получили

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, массив состоящий из одного элемента, хотя запрашивал все возможные.

Comment: Это где это написано, я стесняюсь спросить, что fetchArray возвращает "все возможные"?

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev а если подумать?

Comment: @Ипатьев, хочу метод который возвращает все возможные :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, вопрос из тех, на которые ответ находится за 5 секунд в документации, но по правилам Stack Overflow на него все равно надо давать ответ.

Как видно из документации, [готового метода чтобы получить массив строк в php_sqlite нет](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php)

То есть у нас два пути

Первый - вместо php_sqlite использовать PDO. Там такой метод [есть](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall).
Второй - вспомнить что мы программисты, а не просто складываем сайт из готовых кубиков, и написать такую функцию *самостоятельно*

```
function sqlite_array($result, $mode = SQLITE3_ASSOC) {
    $data = [];
    while($row = $result->fetchArray($mode)){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

и потом использовать её невозбранно для получения "в одну строчку", но при этом не растягивая код как резинку от трусов

```
$sql = "SELECT student_id as id, avg(mark) as average FROM marks 
        GROUP BY student_id ORDER BY avg(mark) DESC LIMIT 15;"
$result = sqlite_array($this->conn->query($sql));
```